# XML add item thumbnail link with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file with this form:

```
<pages url_config="xml/configuration_book1.xml">
<item chapter_id="1" thumb="pages/000.jpg" titlePage="" visibleShadow="true"/>
<item chapter_id="1" thumb="pages/003.jpg" titlePage="" visibleShadow="true"/>
.
.
.</pages>
```

How can I add/delete another "`<item />`" with PHP? Can I use simpleXML and if yes how I can do it?

Comment: Have you look in the PHP documentation?

Comment: I did but what I found so far is how to edit a XML with this form        <to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>

Answer (score 0):

[Add child via simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)

this link will help you more with [XML reading/Writing](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)